# JavaFX program that moves circle with on screen buttons

Tags: java, javafx, event-handling, shapes

I use an HBox to store the buttons and when the event happens, i.e., the button is pressed, the circle's X or Y value is translated.
I am able to move the circle using the buttons, but they move only till a certain point. Where am I going wrong?

```
package application;
    
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;


public class Main extends Application {
//  private circleControl c = new circleControl();
    private Circle circle = new Circle(50);
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            HBox directionalBar = new HBox();
            directionalBar.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            
            Circle c = new Circle(50);
            c.setFill(Color.BLACK);
            
            Button left = new Button("Left");
            Button right = new Button("Right");
            Button up = new Button("Up");
            Button down = new Button("Down");
            
            left.setOnAction(a -> {
                c.setTranslateX((c.getCenterX() - 20));
            });
            
            right.setOnAction(a -> {
                c.setTranslateX((c.getCenterX() + 20));
            });
            
            up.setOnAction(a -> {
                c.setTranslateY((c.getCenterY() - 20));
            });
            
            down.setOnAction(a -> {
                c.setTranslateY((c.getCenterY() + 20));
            });
            
            
            directionalBar.getChildren().addAll(left, right, up, down);
            root.setBottom(directionalBar);
            root.setCenter(c);
            BorderPane.setAlignment(directionalBar, Pos.CENTER);
            BorderPane.setAlignment(c, Pos.CENTER);
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,200,200);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I tried having the circle on focus, but that did not do anything.

Comment: Could you try to put a "Pane" in the center of the BorderPane, and put the circle into the "Pane"?

Answer (score 4):

There are three values to consider when positioning the circle in the border pane.

The `centerX` and `centerY` values control the center of the circle in its own coordinate system.

The `layoutX` and `layoutY` values control the position of the box containing the circle in the coordinate system of its parent (in this case the `BorderPane`). When the border pane lays out its child nodes, it will set these values to position the circle as it needs. Since you placed the circle in the center of the border pane, the border pane will center the circle in that region. (As a consequence, the `centerX` and `centerY` values actually have no effect, though that is irrelevant to the question as posted.)

The `translateX` and `translateY` values (and any other transforms) are applied to the circle *after* layout, so these will affect the position of the circle.

In your code, you never set `centerX` or `centerY`, so they have their default value of `0`. None of your code ever changes these, so they are always `0`.

Your event handlers execute the following lines (depending on the button pressed):

```
c.setTranslateX((c.getCenterX() - 20));
c.setTranslateX((c.getCenterX() + 20));
c.setTranslateY((c.getCenterY() - 20));
c.setTranslateY((c.getCenterY() + 20));
```

Since `centerX` and `centerY` are *always* zero, these are equivalent to

```
c.setTranslateX((-20));
c.setTranslateX((20));
c.setTranslateY((-20));
c.setTranslateY((20));
```

respectively.

Consequently you only ever translate the circle by 20 pixels in a given direction from its starting point, no matter how many times you press each button.

You presumably want to increase the translation by 20 pixels each time you press the button, which you can do by increasing or decreasing `translateX` or `translateY` as needed:

```
    left.setOnAction(a -> {
        c.setTranslateX((c.getTranslateX() - 20));
    });
    
    right.setOnAction(a -> {
        c.setTranslateX((c.getTranslateX() + 20));
    });
    
    up.setOnAction(a -> {
        c.setTranslateY((c.getTranslateY() - 20));
    });
    
    down.setOnAction(a -> {
        c.setTranslateY((c.getTranslateY() + 20));
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch James! It makes a lot of sense now :)